# Filter author names using file names in Git command

Tags: git

I'm working on Git command to filter the author names based on the file names

So, when I enter the following two commands,

```
gh@ubuntu:~$ cd git
gh@ubuntu:~/git$ git log --pretty="format:%an"  t/t0030-stripspace.sh
```

it works great and gives my the list of authors.

However, I need to execute the same thing with the following command:

```
gh@ubuntu:~$ git --git-dir=/home/ghadeer/git/.git --work-tree=/home/ghadeer/git log --pretty="format:%an"  t/t0030-stripspace.sh
```

but it shows this following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 't/t0030-stripspace.sh': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions"
```

anybody knows the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error message suggests, you can get around this by placing a `--` before the path to the file:

```
git --git-dir=... --work-tree=... log --pretty="format:%an" -- t/t0030-stripspace.sh
```